# Custom Forum Database Design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a Forum system to integrate into my website and was wondering if what I have so far is good enough? Any additions/suggestions will be appreciated.

**ForumCategories**:

```
    int ForumCategory_Id
    int Forum_Id
    string Category_Title
    string Category_Description
    DateTime CreationDate
```

**Forums**:

```
    int Forum_Id
    int ComicId // This is the Forum for this specefic Comic. 
                //  Each comic has its own individual forum.\
                //  Forum will be created when comic is created.
    string Title
    DateTime CreationDate
```

**ForumReplies**:

```
    int Forum_Id
    int User_Id
    string Content
    string ip
    DateTime Date
```

I have a separate Table that handles permissions for the Comics that holds permissions for the Forum such as if they can remove posts/edit them etc.

Comment: just a pointer for storing strings in sql server you have `CHAR`, `NCHAR`, `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` datatypes there is not datatype string in sql server.

Comment: @M.Ali Yeah, I know about that. I was just typing it real quick.

Comment: also multiple forums can have the same category, you should remove the `fourm_Id` field from `ForumCategorys` table and add a `ForumCategory_Id` field in `Forums` table.

Comment: @M.Ali I want a Forum to have multiple category's. Does that mean I should modify the ForumReplies and instead of Forum_Id, I put ForumCategory_Id. That would make the ForumCategorys the middleman.

Answer (score 0):

You want a many-to-many relationship between Forums and ForumCategories. That is, a Forum can be in many ForumCategories, and a ForumCategory can also contain many Forums. To do this, you will need an intermediate mapping table.

```
create table Forum_ForumCategory_map
(
  Forum_Id int,
  ForumCategory_Id int
)
```

This replaces having Forum_Id in the ForumCategories table.